# Permalinks don't work after migrating website from apache server to nginx server

Tags: wordpress, nginx

After migrating my website from a apache server to a nginx server, only the homepage works. I already tried saving the permalinks two times and it didn't work.

Maybe the problem is that the .htaccess file doesn't work in nginx.

I want the permalinks to work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the default .htaccess file from wordpress?

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/

Comment: But I think that nginx isn't compatible with .htacccess files...

Comment: Not by default, but you are right, that's not the solution. Did you follow [this guide](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/) from wordpress?